# How to connect Azure DevOps Pipeline to new app service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I've got an app service on Microsoft Azure. I use Azure DevOps to deploy code. This has been working for a while.

Now I need a Beta version of the app. So I've created a new app service in Azure inside a new Resource Group. That was easy to set up and I'm up and running.

But I'm struggling with deployment in DevOps. I've created a new project for my Beta service in DevOps, but I can't figure out how I connect to my new Beta app service.

Edit:

In DevOps I have created a Service Connection that is linked to my Azure Beta Resource. But I don't see how my new pipelines linkes to this sercvice connection.

Pipeline looks like this (YAML export)

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands: npm

steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto '

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: dist
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish artifacts: drop'
```

The strange thing is that the pipeline runs without errors, but nor the Beta site or Prod site gets any of the code changes. What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy your app to an Azure resource (to an app service or to a virtual machine), you will need an Azure Resource Manager service connection first.

Go to **project setting** of the **new Project**-->**Service connections** under **Pipelines**-->**new Service Connection**--> Select **Azure Resource Manager**. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Then you need to create a new pipeline to build the Beta service in the new project. You can check what [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops) are used in the pipeline for the other app service. And add the same tasks in this new pipeline. [Here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition) is an example of creating a yaml pipeline. You can also create a [Classic UI pipeline](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/).

If you deployed the other app service in a [release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops). You can create a new release pipeline for the Beta service.

The tasks used in the build and release pipeline can be the same with your other app service. You might need to change the tasks' configurations a little bit according to the Beta service project. For example, if you use [Azure Web App task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app?view=azure-devops) to deploy your service to azure app. You need to set the `azureSubscription` field to the Azure Resource Manager service connection created in the very first step. And set `appName` field to the new azure app service. See below tutorials for more information.

[Deploy an Azure Web App (Yaml Pipeline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[Deploy a web app to Azure App Services (Classic Pipeline)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps?view=azure-devops)

Comment: "The tasks used in the build and release pipeline can be the same with your other app service". I completely forgot that there is a RELEASE pipeline...! There's the missing link that fooled me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you want to setup Azure DevOps pipeline for your new App Service deployment. For this, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) tutorial. Also, note that it is the same process you did with your previous Service.